# Nuxt generate not clear the cache for new updates

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

#### Versions

- nuxt: 2.14.6
- node: v15.9.0

#### What is Expected?

After upload every updates file  to shared hosting inside dist folder. browser will load new version

#### What is actually happening?

'm using shared hosting to host the project. I'm using  `nuxt generate` command compile it. After compile and upload every update it not effect need to reload the page. Assume my domain name like this `http://example.com` if i enter this in browser it load old version. But if I enter `http://example.com/login` it's load new version but not update the browser cache if I close tab and again load `http://example.com` its load old version. If I load `http://example.com` with old version and reload page it update the browser cache . Also I'm using nuxtjs pwa is there any chance to happen this issue using pwa?

Answer (score -2):

You should use process manager for your application.
`PM2` can help you.

Install `pm2` from `npm` or `yarn`.

- Add application to it and your package file like this:

  ```
  "dev": "nuxt --host domainname --port portnamber",

  "build": "nuxt build",

  "start": "nuxt start",

  "generate": "nuxt generate",

  "deploy": "pm2 start npm --name nameofapp -- start"
  ```
- It require `.htaccess` config :

  ```
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443

  RewriteRule ^index.php(.*) domainname:portnumber/$1 [P,L]

  RewriteRule (.*) domainname:portnumber/$1 [P,L]
  ```
- run:

  ```
  npm run deploy
  ```
- then you should know `pm2` script:

  ```
  pm2 start appname
  ```

Comment: `nuxt generate` will generate static files which runs on ftp not a node server! This problem  can be solved using `workbox` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70496047/nuxt-pwa-update-version)